# TODO LIST with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I made an application of TODO List.

I install the devise and want to define two kinds of users:

```
1) admin
2) worker
```

so I will create the admin controller. for meantime, I created the user_controller.

I want to force sign in, in order to let the worker update his tasks (done or not), so I tried:

```
class WorkersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

p.s, my model's name is user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :confirmable and :activatable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end
```

but, :authenticate_user! is not work. I can create a task even I log out.

and after that, I have to know what is the mail of the user that signed in (in order to update his tasks). so I have to write something like:

```
def index 
  @email = params[:session][:email]
```

but I got an error:

```
NoMethodError in WorkersController#index

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Rails.root: /home/alon/projects/TODOLIST

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/workers_controller.rb:8:in `index'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, email is not stored in session. 
After sign in Devise has a helper method current_resource (current_user in your case, as the word "resource" is replaced with model name).
You should use

```
@email = current_user.email
```

As for the allowing/dissalowing some actions, you need to use CanCan https://github.com/ryanb/cancan